# Android JNI RegisterNatives: Call once with everything, or once per function

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

The idiomatic example of using JNI's `RegisterNatives()` function in an Android environment is to define an array with all of your C++ functions and invoke `RegisterNatives()` once. However, what if I invoke `RegisterNatives()` once per function, each time with an array size of one method? Examples for contrast (did not compile these, in fact I just quickly typed them up, so please forgive any errors):

One call, many functions (idiomatic use case):

```cpp
// Assume static functions `add` and `sub` have been defined
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/company/MyJavaClass");

std::vector<JNINativeMethod> methods {
  {"add", "(II)I", (void*)&add },
  {"sub", "(II)I", (void*)&sub },
};

env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods.data(), methods.size());
```

Many calls, one function per call:

```cpp
// Assume static functions `add` and `sub` have been defined
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/company/MyJavaClass");

std::vector<JNINativeMethod> methods1 {
  {"add", "(II)I", (void*)&add },
};

env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods1.data(), methods1.size());

std::vector<JNINativeMethod> methods2 {
  {"sub", "(II)I", (void*)&sub },
};

env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods2.data(), methods2.size());
```

Any differences between the two other than syntax? I'm not sure if there are performance issues with this, or if this is even allowed. I didn't see anything in the JNI documentation explicitly prohibiting it.

For context, the reason I want to do it this way is because I'm writing some convenience wrappers around mapping C++ methods to Java `native` methods, and it's much easier to do this if I immediately register each individual method instead of building a container and registering that container at a later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem calling RegisterNatives again and again.

Comment: I went this route and noticed no observable performance impact.